# How to attach a plist into an email in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, plist, email-attachments

I am working on a quiz app where the user's input will be stored inside a plist files.  I tried researching for various ways to attach files to an email, but mostly are all for JPEG and TXT files.

I have created a plist and tried to attach the it the same way, but on the mailcomposer it only shows the filename of the attachment.

```
    -(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Answer.plist"];
}
```

This is the code in the composer

```
-(IBAction) openEmail {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"secondary_Example@email.com", nil]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Subject Topic"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Message Body" isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Answer" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"Answers"];

       [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES]; }}
```

Am I missing something out? Please help.. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: seems to me that sending a plist file (which can be easily opened, examined, modified, etc.) is a very *risky* way to submit quiz answers... but I guess it depends on what kind of quiz this is, whether it's something serious or just a toy.

Comment: Yeap am aware of it. Came across many warnings on the net about it being risky. It is just a quiz where markers can see users' input after they have completed it.

Comment: You are giving wrong file name here: [mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"Answers"];
 instead you should write [mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"Answer.plist"];

Comment: Thanks! What a careless mistake! I have changed the file name and the attachment is now visible in the mail composer. Is there any way I can check if this is the correct plist? 

I have a feeling that this is just a empty plist generated for the mail..